# move_uploaded_file changes the file's checksum?

Tags: php

the temporary file in $_FILES has a different checksum than the static file after copying it to the disc using move_uploaded_file.

are there any flags or anything I can do to keep the original checksum?

keeping the original file name does nothing to the checksum

Edit:
hier ist the relevant part of my code

```
$file_name_tmp = $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"];
$file_name_disk = "uploads/tmp_image.png" // uploaded file is always PNG
$pre_hash = hash("sha1",$file_name_tmp);
move_uploaded_file($file_name_tmp, $file_name_disk);
$post_hash = hash("sha1",$file_name_disk);
```

$pre_hash und $post_hash have different values

Comment: Can you show the code that does all this? Maybe it's in the way you get those checksums.

Comment: I added the relevant code chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash("sha1",$file_name_tmp);
hash("sha1",$file_name_disk);
```

You're hashing **the path of the file**. Of course this changes when you move the upload out of the temporary directory!

Use `hash_file()` to hash the contents of the file, which should remain constant.